# Can I reuse joined threads in perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, thread-safety, threadpool

I have a module that is running multiple threads and pushing them onto a list of threads.

ex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#test_module.pm

package test_module;

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub main {

    my $max_threads = 10;
    my @threads     = ();

    # create threads
    while (scalar @threads < $max_threads) {
        my $thread = threads->new(\&thread_sub);
        push @threads, $thread;
    }

    # join threads
    for my $thread (@threads) {
        $thread->join();
    }
}

sub thread_sub {
    my $id = threads->tid();
    print "I am in thread $id\n";
}

1;
```

The problem is that I am calling this module multiple times from one Perl script and instead of eliminating the old threads and creating new ones, the thread ids just keep incrementing.  I have heard that if you don't properly get rid of old threads in Perl this will cause a memory leak and slow your program down, is this true?  Is the data from my old threads just sitting in memory taking up space?

If so this can become a large problem since my script will be part of a much larger program that may generate hundreds or thousands of threads all of which would just be taking up memory even after they are done being used.  How can I stop this from happening? Can my threads be reused?

Here is an example script that will call the module and show how the threads will continue to increment even though I joined the old threads (I thought that "join" was how you cleaned up after them, am I doing something wrong?)  The way this script will be used I can't afford to have memory from old threads sitting there taking up space.

ex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#testing.pl

use strict;
use warnings;
use test_module;

test_module::main();
test_module::main();
test_module::main();

system 'pause';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want thread ids to be reused?

Comment: I guess what I am really wondering is if all of a threads memory is really released upon "joining".  The fact that the ids keep incrementing makes it seem like the old threads are still there somehow in memory even though they have already been "joined".

Comment: thread id incrementing is as much a red herring as process id incrementing. Neither means exhaustion is occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about thread IDs incrementing - that doesn't mean the number of running threads is increasing. Once a thread is `join`ed it has finished executing and been terminated.

However, continuously respawning threads isn't ideal either - creating a thread isn't a particularly lightweight operation in perl. So if you've got to do something like that, and are particularly focussing on efficiency - look to `fork()` instead.

I find I tend to use a 'worker thread' model, using `Thread::Queue`:

```
my $processing_q = Thread::Queue -> new();

sub worker_thread {
    while ( my $item = $processing_q -> dequeue() ) {
       # do stuff to $item
    }
}

for ( 1 .. $num_threads ) {
    my $thr = threads -> create ( \&worker_thread );
}

$processing_q -> enqueue ( @generic_list_of_things ); 
$processing_q -> end;

foreach my $thread ( threads -> list() ) {
    $thread -> join();
}
```

This will feed in a batch of items into a queue, and your worker threads will process them one at a time - means you can have a sensible number running, without having to continuously respawn.

As an alternative though - take a look at `Parallel::ForkManager` - fork style parallel processing may seem counterintuitive initially, but `fork()` is a native system call on Unix systems, so it tends to be better optimised.

Comment: I basically created my own sort of queue, but I will look into that module as it may simplify things.

Comment: It's got the locking semantics built in, which makes it neater. Not necessarily more efficient mind, but clear code has it's own virtue. In particular I like the `end()` option - because then your `while` loop within the sub will return `undef` and exit.